# What does the future hold in store for those of us outside of FIOS areas?

Tags: internet

As you know FIOS is fast, and I believe it will get faster, but what about those of us still living in areas where ADSL is the best solution available. Clearly we'll never get FIOS solutions, but are there any plans to improve internet offerings to those of us who are now on ADSL?

This question is aimed generally at the technology, and not for some specific area. But if you've heard of any success stories in certain areas, I'd like to know.

Comment: please review the faq.  this question seems better suited to a discussion forum.

Comment: "Clearly we'll never get FIOS solutions" Why is this clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that the data rate in the copper lines will increase more and more, but at a higher and higher cost. While this happens wireless data speeds will get faster and cheaper.

When these two trends converge ADSL will start to disappear.

Comment: Was thinking the same, except that wireless comes with a latency price tag. Essentially we need low latency reliable wireless.

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty dependent on country - most non-US countries don't have this divide between areas with coverage and those without due to a better investment in infrastructure.

Comment: s/most/many/ ... i'd bet your statement doesn't hold for much of the third world.

Comment: When I started writing I meant to make the point that places either have good coverage or no coverage, but got distracted!